# Pool volume estimator

Tags: java, calculator

I am looking to make the following code more efficient since it it rather lengthy. However I need to include in the code constructor classes that include accessor methods for the container number, height, radius 1, radius 2, and a method that computes the liquid that the container can hold. So I am looking to leave these concepts in there but make it more efficient if it is possible.

```
public class PoolCleanRequest {
final static double PI = 3.14;
private String num;
private double height;
private String height1;
private String height2; 
private String radius1;
private String radius2;
private double r1;
private double r2;
private String rad2;
private String rad3;
public PoolCleanRequest(String num1){
    num = num1;
}
public void setHeight(double h){
    height=h;
    height1=Double.toString(h);
    height2=Double.toString(h);
}
public void setR1(double rr){
    r1 = rr;
    radius1=Double.toString(rr);
    radius2=Double.toString(rr);
}
public void setR2(double rrr){
    r2 = rrr;
    rad2=Double.toString(rrr);
    rad3=Double.toString(rrr);
}
public String getNum(){
    return num;
}
public String getHeight1(){
   return height1;
}
public String getHeight2(){
   return height2;
}
public String getRadius1(){
    return radius1;
}
public String getRadius2(){
    return radius2;
}
public String getRad1(){
    return rad2;
}
public String getRad3(){
    return rad3;
}
public double getPoolCost(){
    return ((PI*height/3)*(r1*r1+r2*r2+r1*r2))/1000; 
}
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    PoolCleanRequest pool1 = new PoolCleanRequest("1.0");
    PoolCleanRequest pool2 = new PoolCleanRequest("2.0");
    PoolCleanRequest height1 = new PoolCleanRequest("20.0");
    PoolCleanRequest height2= new PoolCleanRequest("15.0");
    PoolCleanRequest radius1 = new PoolCleanRequest("3.0");
    PoolCleanRequest radius2 = new PoolCleanRequest("5.0");
    PoolCleanRequest rad1 = new PoolCleanRequest("2.0");
    PoolCleanRequest rad3 = new PoolCleanRequest("4.0");
    pool1.setHeight(20.0);
    height1.setHeight(20.0);
    height2.setHeight(15.0);
    radius1.setR1(3.0);
    radius2.setR1(5.0);
    rad3.setR2(4.0);
    rad1.setR2(2.0);
    pool1.setR1(3.0);
    pool1.setR2(5.0);
    pool2.setHeight(15.0);
    pool2.setR1(2.0);
    pool2.setR2(4.0);
    System.out.println("Container Num: " + pool1.getNum());
    System.out.println("H: " + height1.getHeight1());
    System.out.println("R1: " + radius1.getRadius1());
    System.out.println("R2: " + radius2.getRadius2());
    System.out.println("Litres: " + pool1.getPoolCost());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Container Num: " + pool2.getNum());
    System.out.println("H: "+ height2.getHeight2());
    System.out.println("R1: " + rad1.getRad1());
    System.out.println("R2: " + rad3.getRad3());
    System.out.println("Litres: " +  pool2.getPoolCost());
  }
}
```

This code gives the correct following output:

```
Container Num: 1.0
H: 20.0
R1: 3.0
R2: 5.0
Litres: 1.0257333333333334

Container Num: 2.0
H: 15.0
R1: 2.0
R2: 4.0
Litres: 0.43960000000000005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously something like

```
Container Num: 1.0
H: 20.0
R1: 3.0
R2: 5.0
Litres: 1.0257333333333334
```

belongs to each other, so why don't you encapsulate it in an object like i.e.

```
public class Container {

    private final static double PI = 3.14;

    private final double number;
    private final double height;
    private final double radius1;
    private final double radius2;

    public Container(double num, double height, double r1, double r2) {
        this.number = num;
        this.height = height;
        this.radius1 = r1;
        this.radius2 = r2;
    }

    public double calculateVolume() {
        return ((PI*this.height/3) * (this.radius1*this.radius1 
                                      + this.radius2*this.radius2 
                                      + this.radius1*this.radius2)) / 1000;
    }

    // getters

    public double getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public double getRadius1() {
        return this.radius1;
    }

    public double getRadius2() {
        return this.radius2;
    }
}
```

You can further reduce the getter overhead by utilizing [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), where you can specify a `@Getter` annotation at the top of the `Container` class which will therefore autogenerate the getters for you automatically

Your main method can then be updated to something like:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    Container container1 = new Container(1.0, 20, 3.0, 5.0);
    Container container2 = new Container(2.0, 15.0, 2.0, 4.0);

    printContainerInfo(container1);
    printContainerInfo(container2);
}

private static void printContainerInfo(Container container) {
    System.out.println("Container "
                       + "Num: " + container.getNumber() + "\n"
                       + "H: " + container.getHeight() + "\n"
                       + "R1: " + container.getRadius1() + "\n"
                       + "R2: " + container.getRadius2() + "\n"
                       + "Litres: " + container.calculateVolume() + "\n");
}
```

As your requirement was:

> need to include in the code constructor classes that include accessor methods for the container number, height, radius 1, radius 2, and a method that computes the liquid that the contain can hold

`Container` does provide all of the required accessor methods and also a computation method to return the liquid size. While the accessor methods are not used directly within the main method (`code constructor?`), they will be indirectly invoked via the `printContainerInfo(Container)` method though. I hope that this still fulfills the requirements. I'd refactor the `printContainerInfo(Container)` method usually to the `Container` class'  `toString()` method but as you obviously need to invoke the getters from the main method I did not do it that way.

To avoid getting confused which argument has to be specified at which position you may also use a [builder pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm) to create your container.

Answer (score 5):

The first problem that jumps out at me is that many of your variables are "stringly typed".  This class is a calculator, right?  Why are you storing your numbers as strings rather than as `double`s?

Why does the constructor take a `num` parameter, and what does it mean?

There is no need to [redefine π](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V98soOyQWKY).  Just use [`Math.PI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI).

Why is there a `getPoolCost()` method?  Your code would be more flexible if you offered a method to calculate the volume, and a separate method to calculate the cost based on the volume.

I don't think that there is much of a reason to define a bunch of setters and getters.  Just define one function that accepts all of the dimensions as parameters, and be done with it.